# "A customer was rude to me" vs. "a customer was being rude to me" in context

Tags: difference, progressive-aspect

Could you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> The other day I got a call from a customer who **was rude** to me for no particular reason.
>
> The other day I got a call from a customer who **was being rude** to me for no particular reason.

Are both perfecly natural in the context?

Comment: Both seem natural, and I see no meaningful difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd understand the first to mean that the customer was rude during the phone conversation.

The second could mean that the phone conversation happened while the customer was being rude.  That is a bit odd, so I might assume that the meaning is actually the same as the first expression. Or perhaps the customer was rude throughout the phone conversation.

Overall, I think the first expression better represent s what I think you mean.